# user error with pub/static folder

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I accidentally delete the pub/static by running the command "rm -rf pub/static*" instead of "rm -rf pub/static/*". Now, i need to run "setup:static-content:deploy -f "in developer mode every time I deleted the static folder. i tried copy and paste the .htaccess file actually the whole pub folder from the magento sample data to my current project, but the issue is not fixed. any tips will be greatly thankful.

Comment: magento version 2.2.7

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to provide full access 777 to pub directory. Instead use this command in developer mode to provide write access to the pub directory

find var generated pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +

Execute this command as a root user from the Magento root directory. Once done change the ownership of Magento directory to Magento user. So you can execute static-content deploy in developer mode as Magento user without any permission issues.

Please find the two links which you useful to set the pre installation and ownership access to Magento directory, files systems access permission commands in developer and production modes.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 0):

You need the create permissions:

```
chmod -Rf 777 ./pub/static
```

Please read this [article](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/rc_perms.html) from Magento Devdoc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answer. I fixed the issues just after i posted the question. so didnt have chance to try all your tips. The way i fixed my issues is i deleted Magento core folder in the vendor folder and run composer install. sorry for replying back late. again thank for answering the question.